# batch store %%f as variable

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

I've been trying to use %%f to operate a script on each file in a directory however however when referencing it through the script the %%f and %%~nf don't seem to be working. I've limited programming experience I'm trying to make a more useful version of [this video formatting tutorial](https://gdion.wordpress.com/2016/06/12/simple-dts-to-ac3-using-ffmpeg/).

So I'd like to store %%f and %%~nf as variables to reference for the rest of the script though I can't work out how.

```
@echo off
set /p FORMAT="Enter File Format: "
FOR %%f IN (*.%FORMAT%) DO  echo %%f
set TEST=%%f
echo %TEST%
cmd/k
```

If I could store these it would resolve my issue, however this is the longer form of what I'm trying to do, this script works if I have the user enter the file manually into a variable (%VIDEO%=%%f and %~nf). Though this is far from ideal.

```
@echo off
set /p FORMAT="Enter File Format: "

FOR %%f IN (*.%FORMAT%) DO (
::IDFILE
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffprobe.exe -v error -show_entries format^=filename -of default^=noprint_wrappers^=1:nokey^=1 "%%f"') do set "FILENAME=%%I"

for /F "delims=" %%I in ('C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffprobe.exe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream^=codec_name -of default^=noprint_wrappers^=1:nokey^=1 "%%f"') do set "Vcodec=%%I"

for /F "delims=" %%I in ('C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffprobe.exe -v error -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream^=codec_name -of default^=noprint_wrappers^=1:nokey^=1 "%%f"') do set "Acodec=%%I"

echo %FILENAME% is using %Vcodec% and %Acodec% codecs

if %Vcodec% == h264 (echo DO NOT CONVERT VIDEO) else (echo CONVERT VIDEO) 
if %Acodec% == ac3 (echo DO NOT CONVERT AUDIO) else (echo CONVERT AUDIO)
timeout /t 5

:: COPY V FIX A
if %Vcodec% == h264 if not %Acodec% == ac3 (echo Copying Video, Converting Audio
timeout /t 5
C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i "%%f" -map 0 -vcodec copy -scodec copy -acodec ac3 -b:a 640K "%%~nf"-AC3.mkv)

:: FIX V COPY A
if not %Vcodec% == h264 if  %Acodec% == ac3 (echo Converting Video, Copying Audio
timeout /t 5
C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i "%%f" -map 0 -vcodec libx264 -scodec copy -acodec copy "%%~nf-"h264.mkv)

:: FIX V FIX A
if not %Vcodec% == h264 if not %Acodec% == ac3 (echo Converting Video, Converting Audio
timeout /t 5
C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i "%%f" -map 0 -vcodec libx264 -scodec copy -acodec ac3 -b:a 640K "%%~nf"-h264-AC3.mkv)

:: COPY V COPY A
if %Vcodec% == h264 if %Acodec% == ac3 (echo "Doesn't require any Conversion")
)
pause
cmd/k
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missed it by *that* much!

```
@echo off
set /p FORMAT="Enter File Format: "

FOR %%f IN (*.%FORMAT%) DO (
 set "video=%%f"
 set "namepart=%%~nf"
 call :idfile
)
pause
goto :eof

.. then the remainder of your code, except Modify the comment `::IDfile` to a   
   label `:idfile` (1 fewer colon) remove the `)` before the `pause`  
   and replace the `cmd /k` with `goto :eof` and replace `%%f`, `%%~nf` with
   `%video%`, `%namepart%` respectively.
```

Two major problems with your code: `delayed expansion` (about which there are many, many references on SO - just use the `search` facility in the top bar) and ue of `::-style comments (which are in fact broken labels) within a code-block (parenthesised series of lines) where labels are not allowed.

The changes I have suggested simply turns the entire meat of your code into a subroutine.

You could also (and perhaps preferably) change the code to

```
@echo off
set /p FORMAT="Enter File Format: "

FOR %%f IN (*.%FORMAT%) DO call :idfile "%%f"

pause
goto :eof
```

and then, instead of using `video` and `namepart` in the subroutine, use `%~1` and `%%~n1` (since `%1` is the first parameter to the subroutine; `~` removes the quotes (there to ensure correct processing if `%%f` contains spaces))

Comment: thanks very much for the help I'm much closer now, however when trying to use %%~n1 for the actual conversion name part I've tried using %%~n1 though it doesn't seem to be reading correctly.

`:: COPY V FIX A
if %Vcodec% == h264 if not %Acodec% == ac3 (echo Copying Video, Converting Audio
echo "%%~n1" (also tried without " " )
pause
C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i "%~1" -map 0 -vcodec copy -scodec copy -acodec ac3 -b:a 640K "%%~nf"-AC3.mkv)`

and it reads back '"%%~n1"' or '%%~n1' and results in files called %%~n1

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
@echo off
set /p FORMAT="Enter File Format: "
FOR %%f IN (*.%FORMAT%) DO ( 
  echo %%f
  set TEST=%%f
)
echo %TEST%
```

or

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set /p FORMAT="Enter File Format: "
FOR %%f IN (*.%FORMAT%) DO ( 
  echo %%f
  set TEST=%%f
  echo !TEST!
)
```